# Maximum length zip code validation

Tags: magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2 , Zip code validation is not working .`
Coding part1:

```
"validate-zip-in": [
            function(value) {
                return utils.isEmptyNoTrim(value) || /(^\d{6}$)/.test(value);

            },
            $.mage.__('Please enter a valid zip code (Ex: 123456).')
        ],
```

Coding part 2:checkout_index_index.xml

```
     </item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                            </item>  
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="validate-zip-in" xsi:type="string" pattern="[0-9]*" max-length="6">true</item>
                                <item name="zip-range" xsi:type="string">6</item>
                            </item> `
```

But it is not working . I want validate maximum length "6" for India.please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

example

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'email_from',
    'text',
    ['name' => 'email_from', 'label' => __('Email From'), 'title' => __('Email From'), 'required' => true, 'class' => 'validate-email']
);
```

above mentioned is an sample format,you can just add any of the following class to avail validation

```
min_text_length
max_text_length
max-words
min-words
range-words
letters-with-basic-punc
alphanumeric
letters-only
no-whitespace
zip-range
integer
vinUS
dateITA
dateNL
time
time12h
phoneUS
phoneUK
mobileUK
stripped-min-length
email2
url2
credit-card-types
ipv4
ipv6
pattern
validate-no-html-tags
validate-select
validate-no-empty
validate-alphanum-with-spaces
validate-data
validate-street
validate-phoneStrict
validate-phoneLax
validate-fax
validate-email
validate-emailSender
validate-password
validate-admin-password
validate-url
validate-clean-url
validate-xml-identifier
validate-ssn
validate-zip-us
validate-date-au
validate-currency-dollar
validate-not-negative-number
validate-zero-or-greater
validate-greater-than-zero
validate-css-length
validate-number
validate-number-range
validate-digits
validate-digits-range
validate-range
validate-alpha
validate-code
validate-alphanum
validate-date
validate-identifier
validate-zip-international
validate-state
less-than-equals-to
greater-than-equals-to
validate-emails
validate-cc-number
validate-cc-ukss
required-entry
checked
not-negative-amount
validate-per-page-value-list
validate-new-password
validate-item-quantity
equalTo
```

Try to make it simple just need to add css class for the rule to apply.

You can use range quantifier {min,max} to specify minimum of 1 digit and maximum of 6 digits as:

```
^[0-9]{1,6}$

^     : Start anchor
[0-9] : Character class to match one of the 10 digits
{1,6} : Range quantifier. Minimum 1 repetition and maximum 6.
$     : End anchor
```

in your cace its `^[0-9]{6}$`